# Show file tree for current workspace in a separate window? VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way/extension which makes it possible to show all open editors in the current workspace in a separate window? Or at least show both next to each other on the left side?

I am used to have both, the open editors and the file tree of the workspace on the left side on top of each other. But this gets confusing and narrow after time and I am not into changing my workflow that much.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option I know is moving one of them to the panel and display the panel on the left or right side:

1. Open the panel: `View -> Appearance -> Show Panel`
2. Move the Panel to the side: `View -> Appearance -> Move Panel left`
3. Drag & drop the "Open Editors" headline to the panel's tab-bar.

Now you should have "Open Editors" as a dedicated tab in your panel.

This, however, is only useful if you don't use your panel for anything else. If you do, you could still combine two panel tabs into one by splitting them vertically, though, but I assume this is not what you want.

[image: Move open editors to panel]

Comment: My friend, that's exactly what I was looking for! I am thankful for your answer.